# 2D array to check whether a char value appears once in the row or column

Tags: java

I have a 2D array, and I am trying to check whether a character value appears only once in a column and row. The code is pretty straight forward. Here is what I have:

```
package MultiDimensionalArrays;

public class latinSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] arrayRefVar = {
                {'A', 'B','C','D'},
                {'B', 'A','D','C'},
                {'C', 'D','B','A'},
                {'D', 'C','A','B'},
        };

        if (Column(arrayRefVar) && Row(arrayRefVar)) {
            System.out.println("The input array is a Latin square");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input: the letters must be from A to C ");
        }
    }

    public static boolean Column(char[][] m) {

        boolean isLatinSq = true;

        char[] tempColumn = new char[m.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
                tempColumn[j] = m[j][i];
                }
            if (!checkColumn(tempColumn)) {
                isLatinSq = false;
                break;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                tempColumn[j] = 0;
                }
        }

        return isLatinSq;
    }

    public static boolean checkColumn(char[] a) {

        boolean isFalse = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = a.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (a[j] == a[i]) {
                    isFalse = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isFalse;
    }

    public static boolean Row(char[][] m) {

        boolean isLatinSq = true;

        char[] tempRow = new char[m[0].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                tempRow[j] = m[i][j];
                }
            if (!checkRow(tempRow)) {
                isLatinSq = false;
                break;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                tempRow[j] = 0;
                }
        }

        return isLatinSq;
    }

    public static boolean checkRow(char[] b) {

        boolean isFalse = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = b.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                if (b[j] == b[i]) {
                    isFalse = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isFalse;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to make this work, does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: Please check out [What can I ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions should be specific; "whats wrong with this code" is not acceptable. What part are you having problems with specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkColumn(tempColumn) return false, and ! is opposite.
so it become true... same for row function.

```
    if (checkColumn(tempColumn)) {
      isLatinSq = false;
      break;
    }
```